# Neo4j gem - Detailed Querying direction with has_many: both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, relationship, neo4j.rb

I was able to do a specific pattern match from this original question [Neo4j gem - Preferred method to deal with admin relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136947/neo4j-gem-preferred-method-to-deal-with-admin-relationship) via this

```
Event.query_as(:event).match("(event)<-[invite:invited]-(user1:User)<-[friends_with:friends_with]-(user2:User)").where('invite.admin = true').pluck(:event)
```

I was unable to get a modified version such as this to work

```
current_user.friends.events.query_as(:event).match("(event)<-[invite:invited]-(user:User)").where(invite: {admin: true}).pluck(:event)
```

So what I actually changed was I changed the direction for the `from_node` and `to_node` in my  invite class

```
  from_class User
  to_class   Event
  type 'invited'
```

It was previously set as from `Event` to `User`. One of my questions is, why did I have to change that to make the query work? Doesn't the `has_many: both` mean that direction doesn't matter?

Another change was changing my relationship type to lower case. In my model it is written in all lowercase which does seem to matter. I thought both would be converted to all uppercase like the way neo4j does it but as it stands right now, it doesn't.

I do think I need to get the current_user method working as I only want the events of the current_user's friends. Suggestions?

Comment: `has_many :both` creates a directionless match when using QueryProxy but every relationship still has a direction. If you create a rel using a `:both` association, like `user1.friends << user2`, it will create the rel out from user1 to user2.

Comment: So it's only directionless with queryproxy but not something like this?

Comment: If you're writing your own cypher queries, you'd need to know the direction of the relationships or you'd leave off the arrow to signify a bidirectional match. `current_user.friends.events.query_as(:event).match("(event)-[invite:invited]-(user:User)").where(invite: {admin: true}).pluck(:event)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I was mixing up two different style of queries

For example in the docs they have this when you have already chained up to the `lesson`

`s.lessons(:l, :r).where("r.start_date < {the_date} and r.end_date >= {the_date}").params(the_date: '2014-11-22').pluck(:l)`

And something like this

```
Student.query_as(:s).where("s.age < {age} AND s.name = {name} AND s.home_town = {home_town}").params(age: params[:age], name: params[:name], home_town: params[:home_town]).pluck(:s)
```

Pay attention to where you place things like `.` and the `query_as` versus the `lessons(:l, :r)` part

My final query that worked eliminated any `match` components because I was already at the relationship and node that I was querying. So it looks something like this.

```
current_user.friends.events(:event, :rel).where("rel.admin = {admin_p} AND event.detail = {detail_p}").params(admin_p: true, detail_p: true).pluck(:event)
```

Would still like an answer to some of my questions above though!

Comment: You don't need to call `pluck` on this. `each`, `first`, etc,... will all give you the last link in the chain: `:event`.